# Select from junction table

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

everybody!
What should I do if I need to make select from junction table?

For example, I develop project and I need to make chats between users. I have two entities: `User` and `Chat`, and many-to-many relation between them (accordingly, I have three tables: `user, chat, chat_user`). I try to get all chats, which user is member, and to get all users from these chats.

I made the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM chat c
         INNER JOIN chat_user cu ON c.id = cu.chat_id
         INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = cu.user_id
WHERE c.id IN (SELECT chat_id
               FROM chat_user
               WHERE user_id = <idUser>);
```

But I don't know how to translate in DQL subquery `SELECT chat_id FROM chat_user WHERE user_id = <idUser>`, because a haven't additional entity for table chat_user.

And I tried to add entity ChatUser and get data in ChatRepository smt. like this:

```
public function getChatsData($idUser)
   {
       $subQuery = $this->getEntityManager()
           ->getRepository(ChatUser::class)
           ->createQueryBuilder('chus')
           ->select('chus.chat')
           ->andWhere('chus.user = :idUser')
           ->setParameter('idUser', $idUser)
       ;

       $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

       return $qb
           ->innerJoin('c.chatUsers', 'cu')
           ->addSelect('cu')
           ->innerJoin('cu.user', 'u')
           ->addSelect('u')
           ->innerJoin('c.messages', 'm')
           ->addSelect('m')
           ->andWhere('u.id = :idUser')
           ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in(
               'c.id',
               $subQuery->getDQL()
           ))
           ->setParameter('idUser', $idUser)
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult()
           ;
   }
```

but it doesn't work. I get error `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 12 near 'chat FROM App\Entity\ChatUser': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.`

Have Doctrine standard tools for such tasks?

Comment: Are you sure ChatUser entity works correct. Please send a query ChatUser and write again.

Comment: Post your entity definitions